# Regex to replace Day of week values with numerics

Tags: c#, regex

I have below string

`q10MTWTHFSSUMT88797sdfsdfsdfws`

where `MTWTHFSSU` are days of week.

I want the below output

`OUTPUT should be : q10j1234567MT88797sdfsdfsdfws`

I tried `q(\d+)([M]|[T]|[W]|[TH]|[F]|[S]|[SU]){1}` but didn't work.

Comment: I think you have not specified the exact requirements. Where does the `j` come from? You have `MT` before `8879` - why are these not day letters?  What are the delimiters? It is rather unclear right now.

Comment: j will be prefix. you can forget about it right now. we need to specify only first days of week, in case there is another pattern like we have ``MT`` need to ignore from days of week

Comment: It is still not clear: which characters denote days of weeks and which don't? In order to replace appropriate text, we need exact requirements. Just replace each `M` with `1`? I guess it is not expected behavior. Or right now, I can even suggest replacing `MTWTHFSSU` with `j1234567`, no regex required.

Comment: Consider this part ``MTWTHFSSU``. it should be replaced with ``1234567`` rest of the string (POST STRING) should remain same even if it contains days letters.

Comment: So, what is wrong with `"q10MTWTHFSSUMT88797sdfsdfsdfws".Replace("MTWTHFSSU", "j1234567");`?

Comment: Because It can happened that a specific day might miss. E.g. ``MTHFSSU``, ``MTSU`` etc. all are valid expressions

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem you probably shouldn't solve using regular expressions.

Use a regex to extract the array of weekday-letters. You can just as well use every other method to just get the portion of the string you want to make your replacements in.

Then just use a loop to iterate over each, replacing it with its value from a dictionary/map.

Also, C# (like almost any modern language) has a rich string library, with which you can replace substrings (in your case, week day letters) with other strings (in your case "1" etc), and don't need to loop.

Comment: which regex can be used, I am not getting regex

Comment: Then don't use regexes. They are not always the right approach.

Comment: Actually we need to process the messages very soon within 1 sec which can't be possible using ``contains`` method of string. That is why trying regex

Comment: If you have not come up with a non-regex solution, why posting an answer? This looks like a comment to me.

Comment: @Gaurav123 1 second for a string replacement this easy should be no problem for any modern computer, including very weak microcontrollers, unless your string is millions of characters long. Also, regexes aren't necessarily faster (why should they) than simple string.replace.

Comment: @stribizhev: fair point. But to be honest: Considering OP's comments to my question, I think OP is mislead in the aspect that he needs a regex and actually needs a solution to a trivial character replacement problem, so I'm answering his question.