# Match exactly one occurrence with regex

Tags: c#, regex

Consider M,T,W,TH,F,S,SU are days of week.

I have regex which is working well except for one scenario when there is no sequence of weekdays, i.e. there is no `M`,  `T` , `W` , `TH` , `F` , `S` , `SU` at the expected location inside the string.

For example, `q10MT` is valid but `q10HT` is invalid.

Below is my expression:

```
string expression = "q(\\d*)(M)?(T(?!H))?(W)?(TH)?(F)?(S(?!U))?(SU)?";
```

In case of `q10MT`, the output is `q10MT` which is correct, but in case of `q10HT` the output is `q10` which is incorrect, my regex should return no value or empty string when there is no match.

What changes do I need to make in order to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, completely useless comment, but I must say that I loved the `(W)?(TH)?(F)` part :-)

Comment: Is it a requirement that the days are in order? IE should "T" be included in the captured of "q10MWT"?

Comment: What about an expression like `q10MTHSSUT` which skips days and extends into the next week. Is that legal? What do you expect as result here?

Comment: skipping days is legal.output of ``q10MTHSSUT`` will be ``q10MTHSSU``

Comment: @Taemyr: order doesn't matter

Comment: @Gaurav123 Then you should be able to use the much easier regex given in my answer... The regex proposed by stribizhev seems overly complicated for this issue then.

Comment: @holroy : actually ``q(\d*)(M|TH?|W|F|SU?)+`` will not work here because I need exactly one time, but by adding ``+`` it can contain multiple sequence.

Comment: @Gaurav123, please update your question with  the extra requirements and specifications that you need to only match each day once. As it stands now there are multiple answers, including mine, which are legal. With the extra requirements, it sure does look like the solution with positive lookaheads is viable solution.

Comment: @holroy : I totally agree with you, but I have already mentioned my regex in question which is defining that I have already solved my problem but failing in one scenario so everything is cleared from question my friend.

Comment: @Gaurav123 I have proposed a regexp that handles arbitrary day order while disallowing repeated days.

Comment: @taemyr : Yes I have already verified that and you have done very good job my friend. ``q10WMTTH`` output should be ``q10W`` but its showing ``q10WMTTH`` which is not correct.

Comment: @Gaurav123 Why should output of q10WMTTH not include the M?

Comment: @taemyr : Because one cycle of weekdays is MTWTHFSSU. After one occurrence of weekdays rest characters will be treated as string only.

Comment: @Gaurav123 So order does matter.  In that case use stribizhev's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it with a positive look-ahead:

```
q(\\d*)(?=(?:M|T(?!H)|W|TH|F|S(?!U)|SU))(M)?(T(?!H))?(W)?(TH)?(F)?(S(?!U))?(SU)?
```

Or, as @Taemyr noted, a shorter equivalent

```
q(\\d*)(?=(?:M|TH?|W|TH|F|SU?))(M)?(T(?!H))?(W)?(TH)?(F)?(S(?!U))?(SU)?
```

Here is a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=q(%5cd*)(%3f%3d(%3f%3aM%7cTH%3f%7cW%7cTH%7cF%7cSU%3f))(M)%3f(T(%3f!H))%3f(W)%3f(TH)%3f(F)%3f(S(%3f!U))%3f(SU)%3f&i=q10MT%0d%0aq10HT%0d%0a)

The `(?=(?:M|TH?|W|F|SU?))` look-ahead makes sure there is *at least one* required value from the alternation list you have after the look-ahead.

C# regex usage:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"q(\d*)(?=(?:M|TH?|W|TH|F|SU?))(M)?(T(?!H))?(W)?(TH)?(F)?(S(?!U))?(SU)?");
var result = rx.Match("q10MSUT").Value;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: yeah, it works very well. Thanks :-) Can you give me easy/simple example to use (?=(?:

Comment: I am a bit puzzled: you must have been using your regex for some time, didn't you? Do you want a sample extraction of the days? Like if we match `M`, return `Monday`?

Comment: `(T(?!H)|TH)` Is the same as `(TH?)`, similarily for `(S(?!U)|SU)`

Comment: q\d+(M|T(?!H)|W|TH|F|S(?!U)|SU)+ does not work because there should be exactly one occurrence. Not more than one.

Output of ``q10MSUT`` should be ``q10MSU`` only

Comment: @Taemyr: `(TH?)` is the same as `(TH|T)`, not `(T(?!H)|TH)`.

Comment: @stribizhev (TH?) matches a T with an optional H. (TH|T) matches a T with an optional H.  (T(?!H)|TH) matches ... A T with no H or a T with an H, which simplifies to a T with an optional H.  All three are the same.

Comment: @stribizhev Stated differently; please provide a string that `(TH?)` matches which is not matched by `(T(?!H)|TH)`, or a string that matches `(T(?!H)|TH)`  and not `(TH?)`.

Comment: @stribizhev : yes I am using regex. I never used  ``positive look-ahead`` so I was asking that if you have any sample example for the same. e.g. any simple string where we can use  ``positive look-ahead``

Comment: @Gaurav123: Look-ahead is just an assertion that there is or there is not some pattern after the current position. You can read more about [look-arounds here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: @Taemyr: In this regex, we need to set different capture groups for `T(?!H)` and `(TH)`. That is why we cannot combine them into 1 group (this is a continuation of an already [long thread (a link to 1 of the previous questions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115398/regex-to-replace-day-of-week-values-with-numerics), and I would not like to break anything at this stage.

Comment: Your rexexp have `T(?!H)` and `TH` as the same capturing group.  I agree that `((?<Tuesday>T(?!H))|(?<Thursday>TH))` would differ.  It's also possibly that `((T(?!H)|(TH))` is different from `((TH?))` although I am not sure which groups gets captured to what number in this case for .net.

Comment: @Taemyr: You should have told before you were speaking about the look-ahead :) I agree. I updated the answer.

Comment: I don't think I have mentioned the look ahead at all.  In your lookahead solution you can do the replacement I indicated inside the actual lookahead, and of course `(S(?!U))?(SU)?` can not be simplified without breaking capturing groups.

Comment: @stribizhev If the capturing groups matter OP should name them.  This limits the potential for latter changes to break the application.

Comment: Why use a positive lookahead, when you can simply use `+` or `{1}` to require at least one occurence of the preceeding group?!   And what about stuff like `q1THSSUM` is that legal (skipping days, and going into next week?

Comment: @holroy : skipping days is perfectly fine.

Comment: @holroy This answers modifies OP's regexp to adress the concern OP asks about.  So it doesn't introduce any errors.  Neither OP nor this answers handles the case of days being in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
q(\d*)(M|TH?|W|F|SU?)+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=q(%5cd*)(M%7cTH%3f%7cW%7cF%7cSU%3f)%2b&i=q1MT%0d%0aq2HT%0d%0aq3SUS+SundaySaturday%0d%0aq4MTWTHugh+Added+random+characters%0d%0aq5TTH+Skips+Wednesday%0d%0aq6MTHSUT++Monday%2c+Thursday%2c+Sunday%2c+Tuesday.+Legal%3f%0d%0a) with some examples on matches and no-matches. The key change in this regexp is that this one uses the `+` to require at least one match.

Be aware that this solution doesn't demand the days to be in order, and allows skipping of days specified in comments not to matter.

**Edit:** OP says in comments that he requires only one match for each day, which this solution doesn't account for.

Answer (score 1):

If order does not matter you need to do something like this;

```
q(?<number>\d+)((?<monday>(?<!M\D*)M)|(?<tuesday>(?<!T(?!H)\D*)T(?!H))|(?<wednesday>(?<!W\D*)W)|(?<thursday>(?<!TH\D*)TH)|(?<friday>(?<!F\D*)F)|(?<saturday>(?<!S(?!U)\D*)S(?!U))|(?<sunday>(?<!SU\D*)SU))+
```

This matches if q is followed by some number, and then followed by one or more weekdays.  Order of weekdays does not matter, and the negative lookbehind insures that no weekday can occur more than once.

Each weekday is captured in it's own capturing group and that group is named so that it can be extracted later.  "q10MTsomething" will capture "q10MT" with 10 in the "number" capturing group, M in the "monday" capturing group and T in the "tuesday" capturing group, other capturing groups will be empty.  "q10TFMother" will capture "q10TFM" with capturing as in the previous example, plus F in the "friday" capturing group. "q10TFMT" will capture "q10TFM" with capturing groups as in the previous example. "q10HT" will not match.

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=q(%3f%3cnumber%3e%5cd%2b)((%3f%3cmonday%3e(%3f%3c!M%5cD*)M)%7c(%3f%3ctuesday%3e(%3f%3c!T(%3f!H)%5cD*)T(%3f!H))%7c(%3f%3cwednesday%3e(%3f%3c!W%5cD*)W)%7c(%3f%3cthursday%3e(%3f%3c!TH%5cD*)TH)%7c(%3f%3cfriday%3e(%3f%3c!F%5cD*)F)%7c(%3f%3csaturday%3e(%3f%3c!S(%3f!U)%5cD*)S(%3f!U))%7c(%3f%3csunday%3e(%3f%3c!SU%5cD*)SU))%2b&i=q10THSSSUTS%0d%0a)

Note that this is the regexp string.  If entered in code you might need to escape the `\`s to produce the correct string.

Comment: ``q10WMTTH`` output should be ``q10W`` but its showing ``q10WMTTH`` which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The question is answered already. Even so I want to point to another idea using a variable length [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for maintaining the sequence, which should be [fine with .NET](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width)

```
q(\d*)[MTWFSUH]+(?<=q\d*(M)?(T)?(W)?(TH)?(F)?(S)?(SU)?)
```

- `[MTWFSUH]` is the list of valid characters. At least one is required
- Using a lookbehind for matching as long as the sequence is maintained

[Test at your test tool](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=q(%5Cd*)%5BMTWFSUH%5D%2B(%3F%3C%3Dq%5Cd*(M)%3F(T)%3F(W)%3F(TH)%3F(F)%3F(S)%3F(SU)%3F)&i=q10%0D%0Aq10FTM%0D%0Aq10HT%0D%0Aq10THT%0D%0Aq10TTH%0D%0A%0D%0Aq10MSUT%0D%0A%0D%0Aq10MTWTHFSSU465689213MTWSU45454%0D%0Aq10MSSU454545asdasdsaMTWTHUR%0D%0A%0D%0Aq10MTHSSUT)

Comment: @Gaurav123 If you don't need the full match (only the captures) could even shorten it down to `[MTWFSUH]+(?<=q(\d*)(M)?(T)?(W)?(TH)?(F)?(S)?(SU)?)`.

Comment: I really liked the way you explained it. Thanks!!